# Is there any easy way to determine what equipment I am wearing?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I want to see what I am wearing, I do <kbd>TAB</kbd> (brings up star-menu), <kbd>D</kbd> (goes to items) and select 'apparel'.

I get an alphabetic list which isn't really that useful to see what I am actually wearing.

For example, when I found a ring and am considering wearing it, I want to check that it's not worse than what I'm wearing now.

When I'm hovering over the ring, I have to run over the entire list to see if some other 'active' item which I'm wearing might accidentally be a ring, and then compare both.

Note that for armor, it does say what the effect will be on armor rating, and I've seen the triangles that suggest the best equipment (but they seem to not take enchantments into account, or atleast not those that suit my playing style).

**Is there an easier way to see what I am wearing**, which slots are empty and for which I have items I can equip?

Comment: Nice question. It would be useful to know if you have a spare slot etc. I walked around for ages without realising I had no boots on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a quick way to see what items you have equipped would be to set all of those items to favorites. then all of your equipped items would show in that menu.

there are only these item slots: head, armor, gauntlets, boots, 1 amulet, 1 ring, two hands, 1 shout/ racial power.

enchantments can vary greatly, so the item comparison only takes the base damage/ armor into consideration.

you should be able to equip any item as long as you have that slot free

Comment: This is a good workaround as long as you don't change your equipped items and know all the slots. I thought I had seen bracers too, do they go in the gauntlets slot then? *mutters at only being able to wear only one ring while having two hands, with each five fingers*

Comment: We want 10 rings! and 13 amulets, Mr.T style!

Comment: bracers count as gauntlets. and i believe skyrim followed the same logic as d&d, you can have as many items of on type as you want, but only one for each slot works.

Answer (score 1):

To see an overall of active effects on you, go to magic then at the last there's "Active Effects", try both rings and compare it via active effects.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out this mod: SkyUI.
It alters your inventory and allows you to sort your equipment on equipped, magical, stolen, ...

Comment: Worth noting that this may be a good solution for the PC release (which we can infer the asker is running from the key-bindings in the question text), but not for players with the same problem on other platforms. Applying mods to console games is… well, problematic at best.

Comment: Good point! I saw the key-bindinds and immediately thought of a solution for PC users.